# Every set of non-collinear points consists of three non-collinear points.

Tags: geometry, axioms

my task is to show that **every set of non-collinear points contains three non-collinear points**. I can only use:
$(I1): A,B \in\mathcal{P}, A\neq B \implies \exists! g\in \mathcal{G}: A,B\in g$
$(I2):$ Every line has at least two points
$\mathcal{P}$ is the set of points and $\mathcal{G}$ is a set of lines which consists of pairs of points.
What I've done so far:
Let $M$ be a set of non-collinear points. Than exists at least one line through two points from M and another point which is not part of this line. Because of $I2$ the line consists at least of two points. So I have three non-collinear points.
This "proof" does not look correct. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: What does the verb "to consist" mean to you?

Comment: Sorry i meant contains

Comment: What if you go like this: "Take two points $P_1, P_2$ from the set ${\cal P}$, then add a third, $P_3$. Then these points are either collinear or they aren't. If they aren't, you are done. If they are, add $P_4$, etc. If you never get a point $P_k$ that is not collinear with the points $P_1,\ldots,P_{k-1}$, you get a contradiction, because "being collinear" is transitive.

Comment: If you rephrase the statement as "every set of non-collinear points contains at least three points", then the proof follows by contradiction.